# Unexplained ArgumentError try to load date from string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Rails 4.1

I'm am trying to add a date attribute to an ActiveRecord object by handing it a string and I'm getting some strange results:

```
t = MyClass.new
t.StartDate = "1/11/2015"  #date is loaded as expected
t.StartDate = "1/12/2015"  #date is loaded as expected 
t.StartDate = "1/13/2015"  #ArgumentError: argument out of range
```

The same *appears* to hold true for any day of the month > 12. What am I missing here? Yes, I could parse the string into a Date object (and I've been able to do this successfully with the same problem dates as strings), but why does my method work for some valid dates and not others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your dates are formatted with `day/month/year` when your trying to use it like `month/day/year`

This is why you can't go further than 12 because 12 is representing the month

Comment: I knew it was something as simple as that. Thanks!